# Cannot perform SMART data and Self-Test on external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

Right now my external drive does not has any errors but I just want to check manually to make sure.
As seen from image below, the option for **SMART data and Self-Test** is greyed out. *Also see the details about the hard drive in image itself.*

1. I tried running `gksu gnome-disks` but still the option is greyed out.
2. I ran `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb --test=short -T permissive` I got this error:

   ```
   smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-15-generic] (local build)
   Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke,
   www.smartmontools.org

   Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi
   command

   === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
   Device Model:     [No Information Found]
   Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
   Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
   Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P
   showall]
   ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
   Local Time is:    Wed Jun 17 11:33:46 2015 IST
   SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't
   show if SMART supported.
   SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't
   show if SMART is enabled.

   A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or
   more '-T permissive' options.
   ```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Same problem here. I can add that it happens in __Ubuntu 14.04__, but NOT in __Ubuntu 12.04__ where SMART is correctly read by both the GUI and the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: Found the solution, see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637450/cannot-perform-smart-data-and-self-test-on-external-hard-drive/692892#692892)

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem. In my case, S.M.A.R.T had been working properly on the device for years while using **Ubuntu 12.04**, and then under **Ubuntu 14.04** it happened exactly what you tell in the question.

The problem is related to a new kernel module that was introduced in **Linux Kernel 3.15** called **`uas` (USB Attached SCSI**) (see [release announcement](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTcyMTk)).

That module is now the responsible of managing USB Mass Storage Devices. [There is a thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1428782) where people complain that `uas` in kernel 3.15 is causing their USB devices to fail. [Another one](http://sourceforge.net/p/smartmontools/mailman/message/33357596/) says that it might be the cause of S.M.A.R.T problems.

Fortunately, those problems seem to be gone at kernel 3.19 (which I am using), as my device is being detected correctly. Only the S.M.A.R.T problem remains.

To fix it, you need to disable the use of `uas` module for the given device.

### Disable `uas` without rebooting

First, unplug all USB devices that might be using it. Then, remove the `uas` and `usb-storage` modules:

```
sudo modprobe -r uas
sudo modprobe -r usb-storage
```

Then, load `usb-storage` module with a parameter that tells it to not use `uas` for a given device:

```
sudo modprobe usb-storage quirks=VendorId:ProductId:u
```

`VendorId` and `ProductId` must be replaced by your device vendor and product id, which can be obtained with `lsusb` command (they are the characters after `ID`).

For example, I have the following device:

```
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0bc2:3320 Seagate RSS LLC SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]
```

So my vendor id is `0bc2`, and my product id is `3320`. My command is:

```
sudo modprobe usb-storage quirks=0bc2:3320:u
```

The last `u` tells `usb-storage` to ignore `uas` for the device (see [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/storage/usb.c#L559)).

At this point, you can insert the USB device, and it will know not to use `uas`, making S.M.A.R.T work properly. You will see lines like these in `dmesg` when inserting the USB device:

```
usb 2-2: UAS is blacklisted for this device, using usb-storage instead
usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
usb-storage 2-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 0bc2 pid 3320: 800000
scsi host12: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
```

### Make the change permanent

The previous quirk will only last until you reboot the system. To make it persistent, you need to follow the steps described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1428782#p1428782), which I copy below:

First, create a file named `ignore_uas.conf` in the `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory with the following content:

```
options usb-storage quirks=VendorId:ProductId:u
```

As before, substitute `VendorId` and `ProductId` by your device vendor and product id obtained from `lsusb`.

Next, regenerate your inital ramdisk:

```
mkinitcpio -p linux
```

or, on newer Ubuntu versions:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Finally, reboot your computer.

---

Edit:
More background on the issue, and another way to get around it without disabling uas (which has better throughput than usb-storage) can be found here: https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/971#comment:12

It seems that kernel is blacklisting `SAT ATA PASS-THROUGH` on some devices when running in uas mode, as they have broken firmware.

So, the blacklisting can be disabled (at your own risk) by using the previous method I mention in the answer, but removing the final `u` from the quirk, ie:

```
quirks=VendorId:ProductId:
```

Please note, however, that I have not tested this approach.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 15.10 with Linux kernel 4.2, I did what you said, but I it is not working for me

Comment: @edwardtorvalds is it the GUI what doesn't work, or also `smartctl`? In my case GUI remains greyed out (I haven't rebooted yet), but `smartctl` works.

Comment: GUI does not work and with `smartctl` it gives `sudo: smartctl: command not found`. If I try to install it says `Package smartctl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`

Comment: @edwardtorvalds the package name is `smartmontools`, I thought you had it installed, as in the question you talk about it

Comment: your method is not working for me

Comment: Running 16.04 / Kernel 4.4.0, I couldn't rsync between two USB drive (frequent and random hangs). And I couldn't check smart data either. Removing uas following your instructions solved both problems. Apparently no more errors, and I can see SMART data in Disks... I'm now going to make the fix permanent. Mucho thanks!

Comment: No mkinitcpio in 16.04.
Ain't it
"sudo update-initramfs -u"
instead now?

Comment: Great answer!  I am able to access my Seagate USB drive and get all the smartctl data from it.  I did try your edit there with the removal of the `u` and that unfortunately hung the drive so I couldn't get any SMART data and the boot time was slow.  However, I added back the `u` and it works perfect.

Comment: Does disabling UAS make it degrade to USB block storage? UAS is drastically faster! UAS supports native command queuing and concurrent USB 3.0 streams, USB block storage is a completely sequential one-at-a-time protocol and uses a simple interrupt pipe.

Comment: For more than one, it looks like: `quirks=0bc2:ab24:u,0bc2:ac30:u`

Comment: @doug65536 can confirm the performance difference. I get 5 times the performance with UAS.

Comment: This wouldn't still be the problem in 2021 would it?

Comment: https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/SAT-with-UAS-Linux

Comment: @endolith I just tested it with Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.13.0-27-generic and without the ignoreuac it still fails on the smartctl.

Comment: For me the https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/971#comment:12 solution did the trick. It seems newer Seagate USB drives don't have that bug anymore, so you can disable the `SAT ATA PASS-THROUGH` blacklisting for those drives (all Seagate drives, e.g. all drives with `VendorID` = `0bc2`, have `SAT ATA PASS-THROUGH` blacklisted in the kernel).

Answer (score 10):

External drives (via USB, I assume) are tricky with SMART. Some don't work at all. The `smartmontools` people posted [a list of hard drives with command-line switches to add to `smartctl`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices) (see fifth column).

---

For Seagate Expansion drives in particular, it looks like you need either `-d sat` or `-d sat,12`. Try the following:

```
sudo smartctl -d sat --all /dev/sdb
sudo smartctl -d sat,12 --all /dev/sdb
```

If one of those works, it tells you which `-d` switch to add to your `smartctl` commands.

Comment: both are giving me error [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11729151/)

Comment: the name of external hdd is : Seagate Expansion External. it seems to be supported but still the options are giving error

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds Did you figure it out?  `0x0bc2:0x331a` doesn't work with these either.

Comment: @endolith nah man.

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds I temporarily disabled UAS https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/SAT-with-UAS-Linux

Comment: @endolith I am not sure what you are doing. But whatever you do please check documentation or some recent answer. Good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

Just an update I am adding on to [Alvaro's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/692892/231142)

Just tested this in Ubuntu 18.04 for an external Seagate drive that I have where I could not get `smartctl` to read the drive at all.  It did require a reboot because I did not want to get behind my system and mess with the USB connections.

First ran `lsusb` and got all my info for the drive:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0bc2:a0a4 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Desktop Drive
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1532:0118 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c215 Logitech, Inc. Extreme 3D Pro
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1532:005b Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

As you can see my drive has the name `Seagate` in it, so all I had to do is to run the following line to add the info to the `/etc/modprode.d/ignore_uas.conf` file:

```
echo options usb-storage quirks=$(lsusb | awk '/Seagate/ {print $6}'):u | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ignore_uas.conf
```

Just remember to replace `Seagate` with the name of your drive.  Now when I look at `/etc/modprode.d/ignore_uas.conf` I see it as:

```
~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/ignore_uas.conf 
options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:a0a4:u
```

Then just run the `update-initramfs` for the changes to become permanent:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Then reboot your system.  Now the smartctl is able to read my external drive.

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdf
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-43-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1E6166
Serial Number:    W1F3DNG2
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 06a323610
Firmware Version: SC47
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jan 11 23:07:43 2019 MST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  592) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 336) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3081) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   108   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       19766104
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   094   091   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       3944
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   052   048   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       231936780154
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   058   058   000    Old_age   Always       -       36793
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       3942
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       894 897 1362
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   056   039   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 44 (Min/Max 44/44 #237)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3909
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   020   020   000    Old_age   Always       -       161838
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   044   061   000    Old_age   Always       -       44 (0 13 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8558h+07m+38.053s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       14574986552
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       18776308038

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: After this change my drive won't mount anymore. Why ?

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil I have never heard of that causing the drive not to mount properly. You can try https://askubuntu.com/a/952275/231142 to set up a more permanent if the drive is seen in `gnome-disks`.

Comment: The issue with this answer is that you will loose the performance associated with the `uas` driver.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa I have now tested your statement with my USB drive both ways and they produce the exact same speed with it enabled or disabled.

Comment: Which I could edit my comment as I forgot to add in order to be read "(..) theoretically you will loose the performance". What's the driver reported for the device in `lsusb -tv` ?

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa `Driver=usb-storage` but if I turn off the ignoreUAC I cannot run smartctl on my drive.  By the way, I am the 3rd or 4th person here with this answer. Why are you singling me out?

Comment: I wanted to be sure as apparently there are Seagate drives where smartctl **does** work with the `uas` driver. At least mine does, after adding the `usb-quirks` line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

Answer (score 4):

I had two Seagate drives connected so I modified @Terrance command to:

`echo "options usb-storage quirks=$(lsusb | awk '/Seagate/ {print $6":u"}' | tr '\n' ',' | head -c-1)" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ignore_uas.conf`

Which gives a correct separator (and flag repetition) for multiple elements:

`options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:3320:u,0bc2:2323:u`

This substitution of 'newline' characters by ',' is probably not made in the most elegant way (requires to remove the extra separator using `head`), but it seems to work.

Then:

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

And reboot as in original answer.

Comment: Good find!  I didn't think about multiple drives at the time I tested mine.  I really like this!  +1

Answer (score 1):

check the table with [supported USB Devices](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices) ...

the switch `-d sat` indicates, that it's supposed to be a drive with SATA port.

there are specific switches for certain [USB bridges](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/USB) - `lsusb` might show the concrete name. if the bridge controller might have a bad implementation - just try to connect it native through SATA instead of USB.

SCSI and ATA (according to the shell output) are probably not what you are looking for :)

Comment: I am using cable which came with hdd when i bought it. you might wanna see these errors: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11729151/)

Comment: the name of external hdd is : Seagate Expansion External. it seems to be supported but still the options are giving error

Comment: @edwardtorvalds there are two basic preconditions... having SMART enabled in BIOS/UEFI for the port (if applicable) and to have it enabled through software, before trying to read it... `smartctl -T permissive --smart=on /dev/sdb` (while the logs look like it would be talking to the wrong port)

Comment: there is no boot option for that, i tried above command i got this [error](http://sprunge.us/GiBj)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds seems it's still sending SCSI commands... that -d sat switch is missing `smartctl -d sat -T permissive --smart=on /dev/sdb` ...and as I've wrote above `lsusb` should list which bridge it is.

Comment: `Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:2312 Seagate RSS LLC `