# Plex and Newshosting/Couch Potato and SZBND

Tags: plex

can someone assist me.  I'm new to Linux and setting up nmy plex media Server.  I have the following issues.

1. I source movies from NH and some are playable in Plex and some are not.  The playable ones have 1 file in the folder and non playable file has multiple brown looking packages in the folder
2. I have also installed CP and SBZ and have added movies in CP but when do they hit SZB and start downloading?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Cheers!!!

Comment: I am not sure what CP or SBZ is, but the files with the brown looking package icons on them are compressed files like zip files and need to have the files extracted from them before Plex can play them.

Comment: Hi Terrance, thanks for you reply and my apologies for just answering. I was on the road and as mentioned new to all of this so sorry if im not explaining myself correctly.  CP is Couch Potato and SBZ is actually SABnzbd.  Im a bit confused and I believe this is the issue.  I use Newshosting to search for the media and so far only 2 of the movies downloaded are playable in Plex. The others are not unpacking.  Regarding Couch Potato I have selcted a bunch of files but cannot see them downlaoding at any time in SABnzbd however I saw a few error messages in SABnzbd.

Comment: based on your comments above, is there a solution to automatically unpacking those zip files in a way that Plex can play them?  How does this works for everyone else?

Comment: In addition, I have a 2nd Hard Drive (4TBs) where the downloaded media are stored to, could this be an issue as well preventing the files from unpacking?

Comment: Plex doesn't care where you put the uncompressed video files.  You can put them in any folder you want.  However, if your second drive is external that you mount by double-clicking in a file manager, Plex cannot read the folders.  So those cannot be added to the library.   If the mount to your 4TB drive is added through the `/etc/fstab` file as a permanent mount it will work fine upon adding them to your library.   I would suggest going through the documentation on Plex:  https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us

Comment: Hi Rerrance, this is what the .../etc/FStab file looks like # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
## <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation UUID=00b43070-2709-4247-bbf8-982934a50f64 / ext4   errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installationUUID=b82016cc-073f-47a5-9db4-5d44dda81683 none  swap sw  0   0

Comment: I added an answer for you to help with setting a mount point for that drive.  As far as the couch potato or the SBZ goes, I really don't have too much info on those ones and I won't be much help on them.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you do not have the 4TB drive set to automatically mount in the same location every time you boot your system, which can cause a problem with Plex's library to be able to see your drive.

To give your drive a mount point that it can use at every startup, first create a folder to be used as a mount point.  Since mine is an external Seagate drive, I created a folder called `/media/Seagate` for the drive.

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/Seagate
```

Next, you can either add the drive manually to the `/etc/fstab` file, or you can use `gnome-disks`.  To install `gnome-disks` run the following from a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility
```

Then to get into `gnome-disks` run the following from a terminal:

```
gnome-disks
```

Now in the application, go and find your drive in the left column, select the partition of the drive that you are going to use and click on the gear icon to bring up the menu:  *(yes, I know, I have lots of drives in this system.)*

[image]

From the drop down menu, select Edit Mount Options:

[image]

In the Mount Options, set it like the following.  *I like to use `nofail` as an option so just in case the external USB drive is not connected the system will still boot up OK*:

[image]

Click OK after completed.  I would now recommend a reboot for the mount to take effect.

After your system is back up, now you should be able to add your folders from the external drive to your Plex library so that it can automatically add your media files for you to play:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are awesome, this worked well.  I am just now having the second issue where Couch Potato is not dropping any of the selected files for download into SABnzbd.  Not sure how to fix that.  Any additional help would again be much appreciated......