# New Ubuntu Server

Tags: hard-drive

My Windows Home Server finally died and I rebuild another pc to take it's place. I no longer have the server software so I thought I'd try getting Ubuntu with either Kodi or Emby to stream my movies.

! currently have a primary drive the Ubuntu will live and 2 other hard drives from my windows server with movies only.

Will I be able to plug my old hard drives in and have Emby or Kodi use it to watch and add movies to or are those movies lost? I just don't want to waste my time trying to get the movies working if it's not possible.

Comment: It depends partly on how the 'server' died - if it died because the hard drives stopped functioning then you're in trouble since that may not work.  Otherwise, Jos' answer of "short answer: yes" is accurate.

Comment: I tested the drives on another pc and both drives are good. Both drives are internals but would it matter if they were usb drives?

Comment: Yes, as long as the drives are working, it will work fine in Ubuntu.  I use the Plex Media Server but I did have to make sure that I gave those drives permanent mount points as automount does not work properly.  https://askubuntu.com/a/952275/231142

Comment: No problem.  In that link that covers for the USB external drive I have.  Works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer: Yes.

To the server, the movies on your drives will be just data. All Windows-readable movie formats are readable by Ubuntu. The Windows filesystem that the movies reside on will be NTFS or FAT, which are also readable and writable by a modern Ubuntu system. Those movies are not lost at all.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please consider marking the question as "answered".