# Smartctl ceased to work after recent updates

Tags: server, usb, usb-drive, smart

After some recent updates my server told me that it couldn't find my external backup disk anymore which was mounted using its disk ID.

So I checked and noticed that the ID for my external backup drive had changed: from ata-ST3000DM001… to usb-Seagate_Expansion_Desk…

Fair enough, ok it's a USB drive. But then my backup script complained that it couldn't read the SMART data, which was never a problem before with the previous identifier.

I *could* remove the smart check from my script but I don't see that as an option since it would mean that I won't get notified if this disk breaks.

---

Things I have tried so far:

smartctl -d sat -a /dev/disk/by-id/usb-…

smartctl (-d sat) -a /dev/sda

reboot

---

Useful Information:

```
lsusb:
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bc2:331a Seagate RSS LLC

smartctl:
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-122-generic] (local  build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke,   www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.

uname:
4.4.0-122-generic
```

---

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acording to a [ticket](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/971) in a smartctl tracker, this is a known bug and modern kernels disable SAT ATA PASS-THROUGH for seagate enclosures, when in UAS mode due to problems with **some** of them.

Fortunately, enclosure with id `0bc2:331a` seems to be fully functional if you disable this behavior.

To do so you should add

```
quirks=0bc2:331a:
```

option to `usb-storage` module.

Alternatively, you could disable UAS. In this case  use

```
quirks=0bc2:331a:u
```

option.

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/692892/259914) to be very helpful in understanding how to properly apply this module option.

Comment: It might help to explain how they would add that to the module.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has solved the problem for now! Now I just need to wait till the end of next week to see if that change has any impact on my transfer rates!