# unable to access usb harddrive with smartctl

Tags: usb-drive, smart

I want to test an usb harddrive with smartctl in ubuntu disco.

```
alex@Guilmon:~$ LANG=C
alex@Guilmon:~$ sudo smartctl -d usbjmicron --all /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-36-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: empty IDENTIFY data

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options
```

the option -d usbjmicron I get from [smartmontools.org/wiki/](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices)

```
lsusb | grep -i micron
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20329 SATA Bridge
```

and smartctl --scan shows it also

```
sudo smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/sdc -d usbjmicron # /dev/sdc [USB JMicron], ATA device
```

Fdisk and parted hangs after a while.

```
Nov 27 16:35:16 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 27 16:35:16 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
Nov 27 16:35:16 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
Nov 27 16:35:16 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 27 16:35:16 Guilmon kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 flags 0
Nov 27 16:35:16 Guilmon kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
Nov 27 16:36:30 Guilmon sudo[14829]:     alex : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/alex ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Nov 27 16:38:17 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 27 16:38:17 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
Nov 27 16:38:17 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
Nov 27 16:38:17 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 8a 47 80 00 00 08 00
Nov 27 16:38:17 Guilmon kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 59393920 flags 80700
Nov 27 16:41:18 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 27 16:41:18 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
Nov 27 16:41:18 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
Nov 27 16:41:18 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 8a 4f fe 00 00 02 00
Nov 27 16:41:18 Guilmon kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 59396094 flags 80700
Nov 27 16:44:20 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 27 16:44:20 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
Nov 27 16:44:20 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
Nov 27 16:44:20 Guilmon kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 27 16:44:20 Guilmon kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 flags 0
Nov 27 16:44:20 Guilmon kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
```

filesystem

```
sudo lsblk -f | grep sdc
sdc                                                                           
├─sdc1 ext4   bionic      8cc02316-1cd7-4f54-bd1a-c3f174e55251  #my bionic installation              
├─sdc2 swap               f923fdf9-3416-420d-898c-e481c82a757b                
├─sdc3                                                                        
└─sdc5 ext4   bionic-home f7217969-9cde-4eff-940b-761ebb06189b #old debian home
```

filesystemcheck

```
sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdc1
[sudo] password for alex: 
e2fsck 1.44.6 (5-Mar-2019)
bionic: recovering journal
bionic: clean, 373117/1602496 files, 2540186/6400000 blocks
alex@Guilmon:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdc5
e2fsck 1.44.6 (5-Mar-2019)
bionic-home: clean, 161503/28672000 files, 102109567/114672128 blocks
```

when I plugin the harddrive it mounts well. But yesterday my filemanager hangs during I search for datas on it.

The harddrive was tested before I replace it with a greater one, and is not used very often. 
How can I check this harddrive. I tried several cabels. I have only one chassis.

Note I can boot my bionic on it without any Problems.

sorry for much text.

Now i get fdisk output

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: IB-272StU-OT    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000e2cd8

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1           2048  51202047  51200000  24,4G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2       51202048  59394047   8192000   3,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc3       59396094 976773119 917377026 437,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sdc5       59396096 976773119 917377024 437,5G 83 Linux
```

Comment: This might help.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1109065/231142

Comment: Thank's @Terrance. but in my case it seems to be a problem is in the udisksd daemon. I have non of this problems with my debian. I stopped the udisks2.service and now I habe access with smartctl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in my case the udisksd daemon througs errors

```
udisksd[657]: Error performing initial housekeeping for drive /org/freedesktop /UDisks2/drives/WDC_WD5000BPVT_22A1YT0_WD_WXM1C52T8295: Error updating SMART data: sk_disk_smart_read_data: Operation not supported (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I was searching around and found an [older bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53475)

I expand my udev rule for my backup-skript

```
ENV{ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SMART}="0", ENV{ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SMART_ENABLED}="0"
```

Now the feature for smartd is disabled for this hardrive.

```
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SMART=0
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SMART_ENABLED=0
```