# Thunar crashed while transferring files, now my drive is cooked

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

I was transferring some files to a portable drive and thunar crashed and now my 4tb drive is unrecognized. I've had a similar problem before which was resolved by using a partition recovery tool, but I've tried that plus many others and none are able to fix it, most cant even detect it.

CHKDSK says: cannot open volume for direct access, even in safe mode

gparted 'partition' 'check' fails with [this log](https://pastebin.com/JHpyqZGM/?e=1) but it does recognize the drive
[image]

testdisk finds the drive and a partition but freezes on selection of 'quick search'
[image]

sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.65 TiB, 4000752599040 bytes, 7813969920 sectorsDisk model: Elements 25A1Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytesSector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytesI/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytesDisklabel type: gptDisk identifier: 13DA21F1-8582-4328-A827-56811CD1B8F7Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type/dev/sdc1   2048 7813967871 7813965824  3.7T Microsoft basic data
```

lsblk

```
sdc           8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdc1        8:33   0   3.7T  0 part
```

testdisk -lu

```
Disk /dev/sdc - 4000 GB / 3725 GiB - CHS 486397 255 63
Sector size:512
Model: WD Elements 25A1, FW:1014
```

I tried ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 which reported a fix, but it had no noticeable effect.

I think the data is still there, the drives still responsive and being detected, but restoring the partition is proving very difficult.

Does anyone have any idea what I could try? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

*EDIT:

smartctl reads the device and gives [this output](https://pastebin.com/MuJDFSmu)

also sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb gives

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.65 TiB, 4000752599040 bytes, 7813969920 sectors
Disk model: Elements 25A1   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 13DA21F1-8582-4328-A827-56811CD1B8F7

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7813967871 7813965824  3.7T Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: Can you try to manually mount it? `sudo mount  /dev/sdb1 /mnt`. What is the result? Copy just the text, no need for images. By the way, it would be strange for Thunar to _cook_ a drive. There was probably some inconsistency in the filesystem or a hardware problem.

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/a/1109065/231142 might help to allow for full access to an external drive.

Comment: @Eduardo unfortunately not, that gives: 'special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist." Terrance I was able to read the device using smartctl, I attached the output in my OP, though I'm still unable to recover the partition

Comment: Does photorec  can extract files ?

Comment: Sorry, I typed /dev/sdb1, please use your actual device: `sudo mount /dev/sdbX1 /mnt`, where X is the letter assigned to it (from your fdisk we know it is the first partition).

Comment: Ok with /sdb1 it gives the 'does not exist' error but I tried again with 'mount /sdb' and this time it gave `/dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.` though it isn't mounted

Comment: Is your drive attached to a dual boot system and do you have Windows as well?  If you do, I would try to run `chkdsk` from Windows on it to see if it can repair the NTFS on the drive.  I have not have much success with `ntfsfix` in Linux.

Comment: My PC is Xubuntu only, but I have a win7 PC, I tried 'chkdsk' there but it says 'cannot open volume for direct access' it does that in safe mode too. I installed win10 on a laptop and it does the same. I made a live USB with minitool and ran 'chkdsk' from that and still the same result. My windows PC/laptop wont even boot when the drives plugged in, its like they get stuck reading it or something. I'm surprised nothing will read it as it was only a thunar crash and it's still operating and recognized by smartctl/device manager etc. I'm out of ideas atm though. Any suggestions would be great