USB external disks encrypted with LUKS not providing SMART data
I have a Seagate external 5TB "expansion" disk, connected over USB. It is encrypted using LUKS.
The disk started clicking and re-spinning suspiciously.
So I want to see the SMART data to see if it's faulty.
Unfortunately, Ubuntu 23.10 can't achieve that. smartctl doesn't give anything for one drive, and for other, practically anything as well:
sudo smartctl -d auto  --tolerance=permissive -a  /dev/sdc1
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Seagate
Product:              Basic
Revision:             0712
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        5.000.981.077.504 bytes [5,00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Logical Unit id:      0x3e423138394d4457
Serial number:        NB189MDW
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Apr  2 14:43:51 2024 CEST
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

The -T permissive does not help, updating the disk database neither.
I have found some tips to disable UAT on a forum, from which I add a part below. But I did not follow on that as it has significant performance impact on all disks as I understand.
Any better way to make it work?
Perhaps some app from Seagate?
Or some trick for disks with LUKS?

sudo xed /etc/modprobe.d/disable-uas.conf

Add the line then save:
options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:2323:u

Rebuild the initrd setup. using:
update-initramfs -u

Reboot.
If you google linux mint uas modprobe, you will see references to this option including one where I mistyped the file name. The file name could be anything. You could create a file per USB ID.

But I'm curoius about the method you mentioned involving disable-uas.conf. That should be probably be posted as a possible answer... I'll try that out next time a get the chance

To go with @kos comment here, you might want to see https://askubuntu.com/a/1109065/231142

Huh so that's what's going on behind the scenes, interesting @Terrance, I never digged hard enough to understand exactly what's going on in those cases (as a technician one should remove the possibly crappy adapter anyways, to make sure it's not because of the crappy adapter why the whole thing isn't working :D), but that's a cool trick!

@kos That drive I used in that answer the adapter in the case went belly up showing that indeed they are crappy.  To get my data off the drive I had to run the testdisk on it to pull everything off as they do something on that adapter to make the 3TB work without performing special formatting on it.  Then I was able to reformat the drive using GPT and drive worked fine for quite sometime after.

@Terrance Yeah I too have recovered some drives simply by taking them off the enclosure and putting them back into a more decent new enclosure. Conversely Toshiba drives IME are often crap and the only good thing you can pull out of the whole thing is the adapter, which you can turn into a poor man's adapter to hook up 2.5" disks on the fly :D

You posted you ran smartctl on /dev/sdc1, should it not be sdc, a drive, not a partition?

@oldfred That was my thought exactly, so I tried both sdc1 and sdc and both returned the exact same data for the drive with smartctl.

" But I did not follow on that as it has significant performance impact on all disks as I understand." ~ only impacts the drive that is in the .conf file.   Also, if you are getting the clicking noise from an external drive it is either the drive itself or the board in the enclosure is going bad.

I think that the LUKS encryption causes sdc to return a different info (more less nothing) than sdc1.

If the drive is clicking I'm sorry to say but you have your diagnosis right there, it's about to go bonkers.
Besides that, I've sometimes had troubles while working as a technician getting some USB drives to display SMART data, the reason behind it being that many USB drives are actually comprised of a USB to SATA daughterboard / adapater, which bridges the cable to the drive, + the drive itself, the adapter exposing the USB port to the outside;
This adapter can often mask the SMART data. When that happened, I used to resort to dismantling the enclosure and attacching the drive directly to a SATA port on the motherboard.

Older or inexpensive adapters may not include uasp. Want for better support of a drive on a USB port
UASP (USB Attached SCSI Protocol) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI
